# MS Dynamics: retrieve only attributes with changed metadata

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

I'm trying to retrieve only the attributes for a certain entity, that have changed metadata since the last metadataquery - for example: if a user changes the requirement on a certain field of a certain entity, and saves and publishes this change, I want a plugin that fires on message Publish & PublishAll to let me know what attribute and which metadata of that attribute has changed.

This is the code I have so far, based on this example on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj863605.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

I get the attributes for the three entities that are listed in `includedEntities`, so no problem there.

I get values for RequiredLevel and IsValidForAdvancedSearch, the two attribute properties listed in `attributeProperties` and the ones I want to watch while the rest returns null, so again, no problem here.

The attributeFilter also does what it's supposed to do: I only get datafields (attributes that do not describe another attribute), so once again: no problem.

The clientversionstamp I pass on is retrieved from a configurationparameter I created, which I update after every query. By watching it during debug, I know that it's the correct value - so I'm quite sure that's not the problem either.

So what is the problem? For each entity, I still have some (about half) of the attributes that are added to the collection of changed attributes in the response, although I didn't change anything.

If I do change something in metadata, that attribute does get added to the response collection as well, so my code does pick up the change. However, I still get a lot more data than I want - the goal is to only get that one attribute that has changed. What am I missing?

```
MetadataFilterExpression EntityFilter = new MetadataFilterExpression(LogicalOperator.And);
EntityFilter.Conditions.Add(new MetadataConditionExpression("LogicalName", MetadataConditionOperator.In, includedEntities));

MetadataPropertiesExpression EntityProperties = new MetadataPropertiesExpression()
{
    AllProperties = false
};
EntityProperties.PropertyNames.AddRange(new string[] { "Attributes" });

MetadataConditionExpression optionsetAttributeName = new MetadataConditionExpression("AttributeOf", MetadataConditionOperator.Equals, null);
MetadataFilterExpression AttributeFilter = new MetadataFilterExpression(LogicalOperator.And);

AttributeFilter.Conditions.Add(optionsetAttributeName);

MetadataPropertiesExpression AttributeProperties = new MetadataPropertiesExpression() { AllProperties = false };
foreach (string attrProperty in attributeProperties)
{
    AttributeProperties.PropertyNames.Add(attrProperty);
}

EntityQueryExpression entityQueryExpression = new EntityQueryExpression()
{
    Criteria = EntityFilter,
    Properties = EntityProperties,
    AttributeQuery = new AttributeQueryExpression()
    {
        Properties = AttributeProperties,
        Criteria = AttributeFilter
    }
};

RetrieveMetadataChangesRequest req = new RetrieveMetadataChangesRequest()
{
    Query = entityQueryExpression,
    ClientVersionStamp = clientVersionStamp
};

return (RetrieveMetadataChangesResponse)service.Execute(req);
```

Comment: The extra attributes that are being returned, do they all have null values?

Comment: No, they return the value of the metadata that I ask for (RequiredLevel and IsValidForAdvancedFind) for that attribute. The value for "HasChanged" is also true, even though no changes were made.

Comment: Perhaps there's an issue with the clientversionstamp value? I would try taking the publish plugin out of the picture. Try running your code from a console app to see if there's any difference.

Comment: I did that, both by retrieving the clientversionstamp from the configuration parameter I had set (and update after every time I make a request, ofcourse), and by passing it on to the function hard-coded, but without success... By watching the value during debug, I'm sure that it's the correct value. 

I've opened a ticket with Microsoft to help resolve this issue, I will post back when I hear from them...

Comment: For those following: I'm still in the process of looking into the problem with Microsoft. They have advised me to update to the latest version, which we will be doing shortly, and then we'll take it from there...

Comment: Resolved: updating to 2016 Online 8.x resolved this issue!